# Style list elements using emotion

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, emotion

I'm trying to style my `react` app using `emotion`

I'd like to make my `ul` and `li` elements unbulleted.

I'm following [this doc from Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled).

This is their example:

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

const Child = styled.div`
  color: red;
`

const Parent = styled.div`
  ${Child} {
    color: green;
  }
`
render(
  <div>
    <Parent>
      <Child>green</Child>
    </Parent>
    <Child>red</Child>
  </div>
)
```

And this is my attempt.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

class Budget extends React.Component {
    state = {
      studentLoanPayment: 0,
    };

    handleInputChange = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        console.log(name, value)
        this.setState({ [name]: value });
    };
    const Li = styled.li({
      color: 'red'
    })
    render() {
```

However I'm getting an `unexpected token` error for `li` in `const li = ...`
How do I target common HTML elements like `ul`, `li`, `p`, `label`?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect, should be:

```js
const Li = styled.li`
      color: red;
`
```

Comment: That probably means you did not set up emotion babel plugin. You can try alternative syntax `styled('li')`

Comment: I also tried `styled('li')` with no luck. how do I set up emotion babel plugin?

Comment: Install babel-plugin-emotion package and add to your .babelrc config: `{
  "plugins": ["emotion"]
}`.  For details check here https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-emotion